# Executing method in Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is the following code in RoR:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
end
```

I've read some Ruby books, but I didn't see in OOP paragraph any information about executing methods of class in class (not other method) body! What is it? How does it work? When is this method executed? Please, make me clear in this question. Thanks.

Comment: you need to go *codeacadamy*.. They explained these..

Comment: Metaprogramming Ruby book - it has all answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method is executed when it is called. In the context of a class body, `self` becomes that class. `self` as a receiver can be omitted, so `validates` here is the same as `Product.validates ...` or `self.validates ...`. `validates` is a class method on `Active::Base`, and is called during the class definition.

---

In my understanding, `self` and an implicit receiver mean different things depending on where it is located.

```
module Foo
  # module body
  def # method name
    # method body
  end
end
```

1. In a module body

   - `self`: the module
   - implicit receiver: the module
2. In a method name

   - `self`: the module
   - implicit receiver: an instance of the class
3. In a method body

   - `self`: the receiver in the method name
   - implicit receiver: the receiver in the method name